# Are these definitions of normality equivalent?

Tags: set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable regular cardinal and let $[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}$ be the set of all countably infinite subsets of $\kappa$. A (proper) *ideal* $I$ on $[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}$ is then a non-empty collection of subsets of $[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}$ such that

1. $[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}\notin I$
2. If $X\in I$ and $Y\subseteq X$ then $Y\in I$
3. If $X,Y\in I$ then $X\cup Y\in I$.

My question is then what *normality* of $I$ means, as I've stumbled across two ostensibly different definitions. Recall that a set $X\subseteq [\kappa]^{\aleph_0}$ is *$I$-positive* if $X\notin I$.

> **Definition 1.** $I$ is *normal* if whenever $X$ is $I$-positive and $f:X\to\kappa$ is a function satisfying that $f(\sigma)\in\sigma$ then there's an $I$-positive $Y\subseteq X$ on which $f$ is constant.
>
> **Definition 2.** $I$ is *normal* if whenever $X$ is $I$-positive and $f:X\to\kappa$ is a function satisfying that $f(\sigma)<\sup(\sigma)$ for all $\sigma\in X$, then there's an $I$-positive $Y\subseteq X$ on which $f$ is constant.

So it boils down to what a regressive function in this context is. Are these definitions equivalent? For the sake of argument we can also assume that $I$ is *fine*, meaning that $\{\sigma\in[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}\mid\xi\notin\sigma\}\in I$ for every $\xi<\kappa$, and *countably complete*, meaning that it's closed under countable unions.

Comment: What is $\sigma(i)$ here? The $i$th member in some fixed enumeration, or...?

Comment: Ah right. Yeah the $i$'th member in increasing order.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense, as that would only allow $\omega$-type subsets, and there are far more countable sets.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I suppose we could fix some enumeration, but in that case the definition suddenly depends upon the choice of enumeration. Instead, I'll just remove that second definition.

Comment: It should be enough to prove that a positive set has limit order type. From there it should be fairly simple.

Comment: If we assume fineness and countable completeness then both definitions of normality imply that $I$ contains the non-stationary ideal on $[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}$ (lemma 3.12 in Foreman's handbook article), so that every $I$-positive set in particular intersects every club, making it $\subseteq$-unbounded and it therefore also has limit order type. But why is limit order type enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer. The argument for the 'only if' direction is due to Stamatis Dimopoulos.

> **Claim.** Let $I$ be a fine ideal on $[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}$ satisfying the first normality definition. Then $I$ satisfies the second normality definition iff it's $\kappa$-complete.
>
> **Proof.** $(\Rightarrow)$ Assume that $I$ satisfies the second normality defintion. Let $\gamma<\kappa$ and $\langle X_\xi\mid\xi<\gamma\rangle\in{^\gamma}I$ be a $\gamma$-sequence of elements of $I$. Note that the second definition implies that $I$ is closed under the following ostensibly stronger notion of diagonal union:
>
> $$
>  \mathscr{D}_{\xi<\kappa}Z_\xi:=\{\sigma\in[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}\mid\sigma\in\bigcup_{\xi<\sup(\sigma)}Z_\xi\}$$
>
> Define $Z_\xi:=X_\xi$ if $\xi<\gamma$ and $Z_\xi:=\emptyset$ for
>   $\xi\in[\gamma,\kappa)$, so that $\mathscr{D}\vec Z\in I$. If now
>   $\sigma\in X_\xi$ for some $\xi<\gamma$ then either
>   $\sup(\sigma)<\gamma$ or $\sigma\in\mathscr{D}\vec Z$. Since
>
> $$Y:=\{\sigma\in[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}\mid\sup(\sigma)<\gamma\}=\bigcap_{\xi<\gamma}\{\sigma\in[\kappa]^{\aleph_0}\mid\xi\notin\gamma\}\in
>  I$$
>
> by fineness, this means that $\bigcup\vec X\subseteq\mathscr{D}\vec Z\cup
>  Y\in I$ and so $\bigcup\vec X\in I$, making $I$ $\kappa$-complete.
>
> $(\Leftarrow)$ Assume that $I$ is $\kappa$-complete, let $X$ be $I$-positive and
>   let $f:X\to\kappa$ satisfy $f(\sigma)<\sup(\sigma)$. Define
>   $g:X\to\kappa$ as $g(\sigma)$ being the least $\xi\in\sigma$ such that
>   $f(\sigma)<\xi$. Then $g(\sigma)\in\sigma$ for all $\sigma\in X$, so
>   by definition 1 we get an $I$-positive $Y\subseteq X$ with
>   $g[Y]=\{\xi_0\}$ for some $\xi_0<\kappa$. Define now for each
>   $\eta<\xi_0$ the set $Y_\eta:=\{\sigma\in Y\mid f(\sigma)=\eta\}$, and
>   note that $Y=\bigcup_{\eta<\xi_0}Y_\eta$. Then $\kappa$-completeness
>   of $I$ implies that there's some $\eta_0<\xi_0$ such that $Y_{\eta_0}$
>   is $I$-positive. As every $\sigma\in Y_{\eta_0}$ satisfies that
>   $f(\sigma)=\eta_0$ we get that $I$ satisfies definition 2. **QED**

Comment: Tell Stamatis that dancing on two weddings always ends up with the dancer falling down and breaking their hip.